# D3.js Zoomable Sunburst not Zooming

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, sunburst-diagram

I have a static 3 level Sunburst diagram -

http://colinwhite.net/Sunburst/

My data is being nested with this function

http://colinwhite.net/Sunburst/js/treeRemapper.js

My approach is based on this example -

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4348373

For some reason my zoom and tweening is not working -

```
var width = 960, height = 700,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
    color = d3.scale.category20c();

var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, 2 * Math.PI]),
    y = d3.scale.sqrt().range([0, radius]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height * .52 + ")");

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .size([2 * Math.PI, radius * radius])
    .value(function(d) { return 1; });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx; })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y); })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y + d.dy); });

d3.json("data/getJson.php", function(error, data) {

var treeData = genJSON(data, ['SourceID', 'ProviderID']);

var path = svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(partition.nodes(treeData))
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill-rule", "evenodd")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name); }) 
     .on("click", click);

  function click(d) {
    path.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attrTween("d", arcTween(d));
  }

});

function arcTween(d) {
  var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x, d.x + d.dx]),
      yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y, 1]),
      yr = d3.interpolate(y.range(), [d.y ? 20 : 0, radius]);
  return function(d, i) {
    return i
        ? function(t) { return arc(d); }
        : function(t) { x.domain(xd(t)); y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t)); return arc(d); };
  };
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you are quoting is based on the "rescaling"/"readjusting" `x` and `y` domain/ranges. In your example, you have defined an `arc` that does not depend on the `x` and `y` scales, thus if you change these, there's no effect.

So what can you do?

First you need to take out the `size` of the `partition` (as you will handle that with scales):

```
var partition = d3.layout.partition()
        //.size([2 * Math.PI, radius * radius])
        .value(function(d) {
            return 1;
        });
```

(remove it, not comment it :) )

Next, you have to use and `arc` that does depend on the scales, e.g. like in the example:

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .startAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x))); })
        .endAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x + d.dx))); })
        .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y)); })
        .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y + d.dy)); });
```

As you can see, the `max` and `min` are kind of squeezing the "hidden" segments...

Cross fingers, run it
(I tried it with flare.json, it did work here)

**Note**

If you plan to also add reweighting when zoomed in, have a look at this nice example: http://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/477c1bfb081b783f80adof

Comment: Wow. Thank you. I would never have got to a solution without this. Have you come across a good resource that explains to laymen, what the math is doing in these examples? The documentation is a little terse..

Comment: Cool! I suggest you modify the constants a bit and see how the formula reacts. From there, you can start by deconstructing it (for instance, what does `d.x` stand for? What is `x(d.x)` then? etc) Try the formulas in the console, get a feel for it :)