# How to draw Zoomable Sunburst with angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

I am new to d3.js, can anyone guide me about drawing zoomable sunburst.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out the [D3 gallery of examples](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock), specifically the zoomable sunburst:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4348373

Code from their example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

path {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill-rule: evenodd;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 700,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

var y = d3.scale.sqrt()
    .range([0, radius]);

var color = d3.scale.category20c();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + (height / 2 + 10) + ")");

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x))); })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x + d.dx))); })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y)); })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y + d.dy)); });

d3.json("/mbostock/raw/4063550/flare.json", function(error, root) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var path = svg.selectAll("path")
      .data(partition.nodes(root))
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name); })
      .on("click", click);

  function click(d) {
    path.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attrTween("d", arcTween(d));
  }
});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");

// Interpolate the scales!
function arcTween(d) {
  var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x, d.x + d.dx]),
      yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y, 1]),
      yr = d3.interpolate(y.range(), [d.y ? 20 : 0, radius]);
  return function(d, i) {
    return i
        ? function(t) { return arc(d); }
        : function(t) { x.domain(xd(t)); y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t)); return arc(d); };
  };
}

</script>
```

Comment: Actually, I tried above code but it is not zoomable, something wrong with click event over there..

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27047124/d3-js-zoomable-sunburst-not-zooming?rq=1